# Issue while accessing post method in CXF rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf, cxf-client

i am trying to create a simple Restful  web service and client using CXF 3.1.2 as below,

Service:

```
package com.rs.sample;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    public class GenServiceImpl  {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/login/{ext}")
    public String login(@PathParam("ext") Integer ext) {
    return "LoggedIn";
    }

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/logout/{ext}")
    public String logout(@PathParam("ext") Integer ext) {
    return "LoggedOut";
    }
    }
```

Client:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
    import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
    public class TestClient {
    static final String REST_URI = "http://localhost:8080/RestfulSample/Restful";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(REST_URI);


    /*
    //Get
    client.path("login").path(new Integer(1234)).accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    String loginResponse = client.get(String.class);
    System.out.println(loginResponse); */

    //Post
    client.path("logout").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    String logoutResponse = client.post("1024").toString();
    System.out.println(logoutResponse);
    }
```

Here i have no problem in accesing login(Get) method and it is working as expected.
But when i tried to access logout(Post) method i am getting the below error,

```
        WARNING: No operation matching request path "/RestfulSample/Restful/agentLogout" is found, Relative Path: /agentLogout, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: application/xml, Accept: text/plain,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
    Nov 04, 2015 3:49:32 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
    WARNING: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:162)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:177)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could you please correct my mistake

Thanks,

Comment: `@Path("/logout/{ext}")`. You need another path segment after `/logout`. Whatever the value of `{ext}` should be

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your response , And here i pass the value of logout client.post("1024")

Comment: That's the body of the request. `@PathParam` is for the URI, so you need to add 1024 to the URI path, i.e. `path("logout").path("1024")`. Right now without the 1024 in the path, the endpoint doesn't exist. If you want to put the data in the POST body, then change it to `@Path("/logout")`, take out the `@PathParam`, and make the method param type `String`. You will need to parse it yourself

Comment: Great Thanks,  It works fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Path("/logout/{ext}")`. You need another path segment after /logout. Whatever the value of `{ext}` should be

`client.post("1024")` is the body of the request. `@PathParam` is for the URI, so you need to add 1024 to the URI path, i.e. `path("logout").path("1024")`.  Right now without the 1024 in the path, the endpoint doesn't exist (hence 404).

If you want to put the data in the POST body, then change it to @Path("/logout"), take out the `@PathParam`, and make the method param type String. You will need to parse it yourself